# How best format input from text file for JQPLOT

Tags: jqplot

I have a script that produces a date.log  file with the below data

```
10:00 1200
10:01 1400
10:02 1350
10:03 1990
10:04 2999
10:05 1388
10:06 1000
```

I'm after a way to parse this into the required JQPLOT format of

```
[[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]
```

I have seen the post where the below code has been suggested for something similar but I have not been able to get this to work.

```
$.ajax({url:"/path/to/Text.txt",
  success:function(result){
    var fileLines = result.split("\n") //result is the file, split on the lines
    var jqplotData = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < fileLines.length(); i++) // skip first two lines
    {
       var aLine = fileLins[i].split(" ");
       var aSeries = [];
       for (var j = 0; j < aLine.length(); j++)
       {
          aSeries.push(parseFloat(aLine[j])); // build array for each series 
       }
       jqplotData.push(aSeries); // add series to larger data array
    }

    // now call jqplot with your data...
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartDiv', jqplotData, {});
  }
});
```

is anyone able to offer me an example of how to parse the date.log file or how to get the above code working ?

Comment: you dont have date in it, its only time?

Comment: That is correct each day a file is written named by the date eg. 21-12-2013.log and within that data for that day is written. I need that log parsed to write the contained data into the format jqplot can read